# bulma: input / button size on tablet

Tags: bulma

Is there an out of the box modifier in bulma to change the size of inputs / buttons on tablets?

```
<div class="field has-addons">
  <div class="control is-fullwidth">
    <input class="input is-fullwidth" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="control">
    <button class="button is-primary">Search</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AlexZeitler/683g70xt/

Answer (score 1):

Bulma uses a [column based grid](https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/responsiveness/) that can be used to control the responsiveness of elements which is initiated by

```
<div class="columns">
```

Column sizes are then controlled through the use of classes like:

```
<div class="column is-tablet-6">
```

Since you are using has-addons, the whole size of the group will be affected and not each item individually. As such, you may want to do a check with your backend language to see if the user is on a mobile device. For php I would recommend [Mobile Detect](http://mobiledetect.net/) then you could do something like:

```
<? if($detect->isTablet()): ?>
    <div class="columns">
         // Do tablet view
    </div>
<? else: ?>
    // Do Normal view
<? endif; ?>
```

Otherwise you will just want to write your mark up in the grid and style as appropriate to appear as if it was an input-group.